# How to parse an XML without ids with xlstproc?

Tags: xml, xslt

If an xml is of form

```
<person>
  <first>Thomas</first>
  <last>Andrews</last>
  <title>Developer</title>
</person>
```

we can have an xslt as:

```
   <xsl:template match="person">
       <xsl:value-of select='first'/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
       <xsl:value-of select='last'/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
       <xsl:value-of select='title'/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
```

And applying the above style using xsltproc the output I get would be of form: `Thomas|Andrews|Developer`. 
How to parse an xml when there is no specific attribute names? For example the one below:

```
  <Row>
   <Data ss:Type="String">John</Data>
   <Data ss:Type="Number">1</Data>
   <Data ss:Type="String">4</Data>
   <Data ss:Type="String">Smith</Data>
   <Data ss:Type="String">US Dollar</Data>
   <Data ss:Type="String">North America</Data>
 </Row>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You parse XML with an XML parser. It doesn't matter if the elements are called "person" or "data" so "parsing XML" is not your problem here.

xsltproc is your XSLT processor. The input for the XSLT processor is a parsed XML document. If the element names don't describe the content (e.g. "data"), then what does? The XML elements do have an order, unlike the columns of a database table, so you might be able to use the ordering of the input assuming it's constant over all input documents. Other than that, I can't think of a good way of recognising strings like "John" as a first name of a person.

If you don't have to worry about the names of the XML elements, this might do the trick:

```
<xsl:template match="Row">
  <xsl:for-each select="*">
    <xsl:value-of select='.'/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
```

Comment: Works. The main thing to be noted is the consistency of the fields. Thanks.